# Why content.js load twice or more when in facebook.com with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension.
The manifest.json is

```
"content_scripts": [ 
    {
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "matches": [ "*://www.facebook.com/*"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    },
```

The content.js just is

```
console.log("say hi");
```

And console is
Please see this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRrkv.png

It called four times. It just happened in facebook.com, not happened in other website such as www.google.com. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Facebook uses frames, but if it does it is possible that there are four frames that are executing your code once each. Chrome console doesn't give any visual indication that this is what is happening. Try setting `all_frames` to false so that it only executes on the top frame.

Comment: Yes, the problem is due to this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You've specified **all_frames**: true. There's likely a few iframes on the page causing content.js to be executed multiple times.